# JSON import in Python

Tags: python, json

I would like to import the JSON file located at "https://www.drivy.com/cars/458342/reviews?page=1&paginate_per=6&rel=next" in python.

When I run this:

```
with open('C:/Users/coppe/Documents/py trials/eval.json') as json_file:  
reviews = json.load(json_file)
```

I get an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 6776: character maps to <undefined>
```

Actually this error is due to a special character contained in the `html` keyvalue. Knowing that this character is an emoticon (a thumb), how can I still import my JSON by ignoring this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the correct format for the json encoder to use. Most use `utf8`, therefore use something like:

```
reviews = json.load(
    open("C:/Users/coppe/Documents/py trials/eval.json", encoding="utf8")
)
```

or

```
with open('C:/Users/coppe/Documents/py trials/eval.json') as json_file:
    reviews = json.load(json_file, encoding="utf8")
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

use

`open(json_file, encoding="utf8")`